# Resolve php endless recursion issue

Tags: php, recursion, observer-pattern

I'm currently running into an endless recursion situation.

I'm implementing a message service that calls various object methods.. it's quite similar to observer pattern..

Here's whats going on:

**Dispatcher.php**

```
class Dispatcher {
...
    public function message($name, $method) {

    // Find the object based on the name
    $object = $this->findObjectByName($name);

    if(!$object->decorations))
            // Decorate the object
        $object = new $name($object); // This is where it locks up.
            $object->decorations = true;
    }

    return $object->$method();
...
}

class A {
    function __construct()
    {
        $Dispatcher->message("B", "getName");
    }

    public function getName() {
        return "Class A";
    }

}

class B {
    function __construct()
    {
            // Assume $Dispatcher is the classes
        $Dispatcher->message("A", "getName");
    }

    public function getName() {
        return "Class B";
    }

}
```

It locks up when neither object is initialized. It just goes back and forth from message each other and no one can be initialized.

I'm looking for some kind of queue implementation that will make messages wait for each other.. One where the return values still get set. I'm looking to have as little boilerplate code in class A and class B as possible.

---

I'm getting a lot of talk about the `not_initialized` method, unfortunately I feel that the discussion is going in the wrong direction. That's my fault, I'll explain the situation a little more (and better I hope).

`$object` implements a decorator pattern - that is `$object` gets more features (methods) when I initialize class A and class B. I need to use those features made available from the decorations in the messaging method, that's why if its not yet decorated, decorate it. I really do not think `not_initialized` would have been the issue because when say `$objectA` is checked it is not yet decorated - So I want to add those methods to it. Class A and B are decorator classes. So not_initialized is correct at the time. It gets stuck when I try to decorate the object. I changed the code to better reflect this situation.

Comment: please provide the code for `Dispatcher::not_initialized()`, because that is the code that yields the error, because it doesn't remember correctly which objects are already initialized.

Comment: Also, what is `findObjectByName` doing? I'm not certain what you're trying to achieve here. Are you trying to decorate a single object with both classes A and B?

Answer (score 4):

This is not an example of deadlock, but of endless recursion. Most likely your `not_initialized` function returns true until the constructor has been fully run.
As a result, constructing an object of type A will indirectly call the B constructor, which will call the A constructor, ad infinitum.

You will have to change the `not_initialized` function, or move the message dispatching out of the constructors if you can.

[Deadlock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock) is a situation that involves multiple processes. In this case, there is only a single process.

Comment: Oh ok, yah endless recursion makes more sense. It locks up when I try to construct it yes. Unfortunately I can't move the message out of the constructor (I've tried - it simply postpones a mountain of issues). I'm wondering if there is any queue implementation that would resolve this...

Comment: you won't need a queue, but you must change hte `not_initialized` method, so it remembers correctly which object is initialized.